# Unable to rewrite my code without goto using PHP

Tags: php, loops, goto

I am using this code and it works. The truth is I don't know how to rewrite it more efficiently without goto. I personally think that using goto (new in php) is OK in this case, but other people are telling me that it's not ok. How should I rewrite my code without goto? Why do you think that my code is bad wth goto? I am not experienced programmer so any advice what am I doing wrong is appreciated.

```
    check_process:
    $random_code = substr(number_format(time() * rand(),0,'',''),0,10);

    $unique_check = $wpdb->get_var(
      "SELECT meta_id 
      FROM {$wpdb->postmeta} 
      WHERE meta_key = 'unique_code' 
      AND meta_value = '{$random_code}' 
      LIMIT 1"
    );

    if ($unique_check == NULL) {
       // OK
    }
    else {
        goto check_process; // go back and generate another unique code if are same
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
do{
    $random_code = substr(number_format(time() * rand(),0,'',''),0,10);

    $unique_check = $wpdb->get_var(
      "SELECT meta_id 
      FROM {$wpdb->postmeta} 
      WHERE meta_key = 'unique_code' 
      AND meta_value = '{$random_code}' 
      LIMIT 1"
    );
} while ( ! is_null($unique_check));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
do {

...

} while {!is_null($unique_check))
```

I guess you can argue endlessly about it, but I prefer this style over goto :)

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a job for a `while`:

```
$check = true;
while($check){
    //do the stuff
    if($unique_check == NULL){
        $check = false;
    }
}
```

Even simpler with a `do-while`:

```
do {
    //do the stuff
} while($unique_check != NULL);
```

Answer (score 0):

What about using a `do while` loop ?

```
do {
  $random_code = substr(number_format(time() * rand(),0,'',''),0,10);

  $unique_check = $wpdb->get_var(
    "SELECT meta_id 
    FROM {$wpdb->postmeta} 
    WHERE meta_key = 'unique_code' 
    AND meta_value = '{$random_code}' 
    LIMIT 1"
  );

} while (!is_null($unique_check)); // go back and generate another unique code if are same
```

Would be cleaner to use this kind of loop rather than a goto.

Answer (score 0):

for the longest time `goto` has been frowned upon, when you use `goto` in breaks the structure creates multiple `exit` points in code which from a theoretical point is really bad. the alternative to `goto` was `gosub` back in the day, the difference was gosub always returned to the calling point when it was done what it was doing. So today `gosub` are like functions.

But to make it all twist if you disassemble some code and read through the assembly instructions you will find hundreds of references to `jmp` which is exactly like goto. So go figure.

Answer (score 0):

goto could be an easy alternative but its bad practice like you said!

The main reason is not the one little goto it is the mass. If you get too familiar with that you will use it often. Thats a problem for other developers who try to read and understand your code. In fact with one goto it is easy but imagine at least 10. It will take much more time to understand this "spaghetti code".

Better practice is to use functions to "jump" to a specific algorithm in your code and if possible use loops like in the other answers.

Here you can see what happens if you use goto :D
http://xkcd.com/292/

Comment: i don't use goto either but if you have ever written assembly code you will realize that sometime there is no other option than goto.

Comment: Your are right! In assembly code you do not have another chance. But we are talking here about php and here you have the possibilties of functions and classes.